# How to build a project in jenkins when 2 others projects must be build before? never mind which one is build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, jenkins-pipeline

I have 3 projects: A,B,C. All of them have a simple shell script using echo comand for my test.
What I'm trying to do with this pipeline plugins, is to make C build when A is build OR B.
I saw how to make parallel build, but nothing is talking about a OR logical operator to be used in my case. 
And I'm also confused between pipeline script and groovy file, I think groovy file is better for this case?

Does someone have an idea about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

A simple make file will do this.  You can call targets in the make file with an ANT build in Jenkins.

Comment: I add the Ant pluggin on jenkins, so what you mean is to insert my 3 jobs in the targets then make a build script where I set the workflow?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.